# Why does my win10 computer freeze when it's Idle?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, idle

Gaming PC was built around 7 months ago. While on the computer, it never hangs, freezes, glitches or gives me any kinds of problems. When the computer goes idle (from what I can tell) over 12 hours or more. It will eventually freeze or lock up. Forcing me to have to force shutdown and boot back up.

I ended up calling MSI (motherboard) tech support just to maybe pick their brain on what could be causing the problem. Their best solution for me was to not keep the computer running when I was away from it. Level 300 IQ stuff right there. My motherboard and video card drivers are 100% up-to-date. I was thinking it could be the defrag process, which I disabled. And windows defender is disabled. Those are the 2 main things I could think of that could run a heavy load on the CPU while the pc is Idle.

I understand windows performs are number of tasks while you're on your computer and off your computer. I just don't know what could be causing the issue. The computer is set to high performance in power settings, but I believe the motherboard has basically default settings.

Another thing I also want to note:
[image]

But I'm pretty positive my main Archive Drive (D) powers down and has to boot back up when it's been idle. Does the drive have an internal mechanism that forces it to power down? It's a WDC 5TB Black drive.

```
Computer Specs:
MSI MPG Z390 GAMING PRO CARBON (MS-7B17)
Intel Core i7-9700K
EVGA RTX 2070 SUPER Black Gaming (08G-P4-3071)
Corsair 8GB X2: CMK16GX4M2B3000C15
Main: Samsung SSD 970 EVO 1TB M.2
SSD Backup: Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB
Other Sata Drive: X5 6 gb/s Various sizes
Seasonic Focus GX-650, 650W 80+ Gold
```

If anyone has any suggestions for me, i'm willing to basically try anything.

Comment: What does Security and Maintenance, Reliability History say?  What errors are reported?  Is there a c:\windows\minidump file?  Get Nirsoft Blue Screen View and see what it says about the dump.

Comment: In S&M All I'm really seeing is "LightKeeperService" Stopped Working on a Daily Basis for MSI Dragon Center. And on Random Days, windows was not shut down properly. Nothing else. I have 3 minidump files. https://i.imgur.com/sAngw7c.png All dated from 01/28/20

Comment: Use Nirsoft Blue Screen view.  What is the main error?  It could be a driver but see if you can tell us what the 0x000000xx error is.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111990/sickest-issue

Comment: @john So far so good. Computer has yet to crash. Granted I haven't left it idle for 24+ hours yet, but I have left the pc on since all those updates. Hopefully we are in the clear.

Comment: So does my answer above help (that is, if I convert it to an answer) and including driver updates  mentioned in the discussion?

Answer (score 1):

Look at Security and Maintenance, Reliability History and see what errors are reported?

There should be a c:\windows\minidump file.
Get Nirsoft Blue Screen View and see what it says about the dump

Update all Drivers for your machine including BIOS.

Then run (from an Admin Command Prompt):

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  then
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  .

Do a final restart and test the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue intermittently for quite a while, now it's most of the time when I leave it idle. Sleep has long ago been disabled. Went through the all Task Scheduler logs and there were 2 entries that occurred when the last timestamp before no entries. That time can be found in the Event Viewer Windows Logs/Security entries because there are about 10/second. I deleted the Disk Cleanup, the other was memory diagnostics which I left alone. I also went through every item in the Device Manager to uncheck the allow computer to turn off to save power. Defrag was also disabled, which Win10 shouldn't be using on a SDD automatically. I have tested three times. No issues. Hope this helps:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150365)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue of Windows 10 screen freezing when idle by cleaning the dust out of the computer case. This can be done by blowing it out using a canister of compressed air. Might not work for everyone, but if this is the cause of the problem you are experiencing it is an easy fix.

Comment: Using compressed air on a computer looks to me like a weird idea. Best way is to avoid getting dust into your computer to start with :-)